# How to paginate sunspot in this manner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

I have the following model associations:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
```

Here is my controller

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  # Using Sunspot here.
  def index
    @search = Product.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    end
    @products = @search.results
  end
end
```

and then my view:

```
<%= will_paginate @products %>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.name %>
  <% prices.each do |price| %>
    <%= price.price %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Lets say I have 10 Products that each have 20 different Prices. My goal is to show 5 Products per page but have the Prices run over to the next page if the amount of Prices on a page exceeds a maximum of 25 at a time.

Here is two different examples of what I want it to do:

```
 Product 1, 2, 3, 4 + 5 Prices each = same page
 Product 5 + 6 Prices = this Product with Prices on next page
```

Or

```
Product 1 + 23 prices = same page
Product 2 + 20 prices = next page with Product and prices
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've a hard time following, to be honest. First off — how can a Product on one hand "have many prices" and on the other "belong to many prices (plural!)"?

Comment: @polarblau I edited by question to give more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to query over the Price model:

```
prices = Price.joins(:product).where(:product_id => [1,2,3]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

And to make things easier for your views: `prices.map! { |p| p.product }`

Comment: Sorry, this is hard to understand fully. Am I searching on `Prices` or am I searching with `Product` still?

Comment: The code i posted is searching on Prices. What it does is to inner join the table Price with the table Product to fetch all the Prices that match a specific set of product_id's. Then, it paginates the result. Finally, the last line of code inverts the resulting set, indexing it by Product.

Comment: One more note. I never used Sunspot but I guess you'll have to split the search into two parts: 1) `@search = Product search do ...` without pagination; 2) the method I described in the post above using as product_id input the resulting set from Sunspot search.