# Sunspot: paginating a certain amount of an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate, sunspot

If I have the following associations:

```
Product has_many :user_prices
UserPrice belongs_to :product
```

And my goal is to show 5 Products per page and only so many user_prices ( lets say 5 each):

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = Product.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      # This gives 5 producuts per page but how about that and 5 UserPrices?
      paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    end
    @products = @search.results
  end
end
```

View: **search/index**

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
 <%= p.name %>
  <% p.user_prices.each do |up| %>
    <%= number_to_currency(up.price) %>
    <%= up.purchase_date %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How would you be able to do this in Sunspot?

Comment: I think you need to do this limitation in the view, where you will show your Products. Because you are searching by `Product` model and it doesn't consider `UserPrice`

Comment: @bor1s That sounds like a plan, I'll look more into it, where would I start, at the will_paginate gem or....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will_Paginate will not help you here, because you already 'paginated' collection of `Product` model. I think it will better for you to do something like this into your view:

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
  <% p.user_prices.last(5).each do |price| %>
    <%= #some info from user prices %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

this is just for example. You can also implement some `scope` for UserPrice model, say to order it or whatever.
Hope it will help you. Good luck :)

Comment: This doesn't work because I have to use the `each` method to see the user_prices. I edited my question to show you what I mean.

Comment: I forgot to write `.each` :), now it should work fine. Please see my updated post

Comment: Thanks, maybe you could solve my other question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113402/how-to-paginate-with-sunspot-in-this-manner